# Windows Azure IP address

Tags: windows-server-2008, azure

I run a Windows 2008 server in Azure. Its public IP address is like 168.62.xxx.xxx

Is this IP address assigned exclusively to my server or is it shared among tenants like in a shared hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Windows Azure Cloud Service gets one public IP address. Azure Virtual Machines are deployed behind a Cloud Service, so if you have several VMs deployed in the same Cloud Service your VMs will share the public IP so you'll have to keep that in mind.

Note that the IP may change over time so using a CNAME pointing to yourservice.cloudapp.net instead of pointing directly to the IP is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I installed only one server in my azure account. So the IP is exclusive right?
Regarding CNAME I faced trouble to run mail server properly because of MX settings. So I point DNS records to IP only. Is there any work arounds?

Comment: Yes, it is unique to you. It will work ok pointing to the IP. The most common situation where the IP changes is when you do a VIP Swap between production and stage slots for Cloud Services (Worker and Web role solutions), or if the instances have to be moved between hosts in the backend by Microsoft, but for VMs it changes more rarely. Remember to open the relevant Endpoints/ports to the server for your services.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I did open the endpoints/ports and things are working well.

Comment: Virtual Machine VIP is now preservable when shutting down VMs but keeping deployment. I clarified this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @David-W stated, a VIP is dedicated to your deployment, with all virtual machines (or role instances) sharing that public IP address. One thing you may not be aware of: with Virtual Machines, you can choose between load-balanced endpoints and *port-forwarded* endpoints. While the former is typically used with web sites / web services (where you have, say, a web site listening on port 80 across several web server vm's), the latter allows you to directly access a specific virtual machine, differentiated by port number (maybe specific database servers in a cluster, for example).

There's a new change regarding VIP preservation and Virtual Machines: Previously, if you shut down the last Virtual Machine within a deployment (cloud service), you'd lose your VIP. As of a week ago (as announced at TechEd 2013), you can now keep a virtual machine provisioned, even when shut down, which preserves your VIP (see [this post](http://michaelwasham.com/2013/06/03/windows-azure-powershell-june-2013-update-for-iaas-and-paas/) for more details).

For Cloud Services, the full rules about when a VIP changes or doesn't change is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/10/19/announcing-improved-in-place-updates.aspx).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all the details. Definitely I was not aware of these.